# laravel set class variable value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i'm going to store data through excel-sheet to database every thing is going well but i want to add user->ID individually in **Item** class there is field in item class **Userid**

```
public function import()
    {
        Excel::load(Input::file('fileitem'),function($reader){
            $reader->each(function($sheet){
                Item::firstOrCreate($sheet->toArray());
                 $this->userid =Auth::user()->id;
            });
        });
        return back()->with('message','Records added sucessfully');;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the context of this import function but `$this` doesn't appear to have anything to do with the `Item` you are creating so why are you trying to set `$this->userid`?

An easy way around this would be to just add the ID to the array you are using to create the item:

```
$sheetArray = $sheet->toArray();
$sheetArray['userid'] = \Auth::user()->id;
Item::firstOrCreate($sheetArray);
```

Comment: Time to debug then, based on your description, this should work.  You really should do some checks in your code to see if the code succeeds.

Comment: is it possible without adding userid column in excel file i can add Userid in sheet Array?

Comment: Yes, that is what this is doing.  I take it, you don't have a good knowledge of PHP so I would recommend you take some time to learn before you jump in to modifying code before you damage something or leave something open to a vulnerability.